# BigDecimal Graphql Js

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I want to declare a "BigDecimal" scalar in graphql.
I added this declaration in my resolver :

```
    BigDecimal:  new GraphQLScalarType({
        name: 'BigDecimal',
        description: 'BigDecimal scalar type',
        serialize: (value) => value,
        parseValue: (value) => value,
        parseLiteral: (ast) => {ast.kind === "FloatValue" ? parseFloat(ast.value) : null}

})
```

However when I call my query as follow :

```
   mutation basePost(  
      numberPost:{
                 amt:1.111
                 } )
```

this gives me this error :

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Expected type BigDecimal, found 1.111.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 41,
          "column": 27
        }
      ]
    },
```

My input schema is as follow :

```
input numberPost {
    amt: BigDecimal
}
```

Where is my error ? is there another manner to declare bigDecimal for graphql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the Float scalar of Graphql to byPass the issue